# Cant use the module 'DynamicFactorMQ'

Tags: statsmodels

I get the error:

AttributeError: module 'statsmodels.tsa.api' has no attribute 'DynamicFactorMQ'

```
model = sm.tsa.DynamicFactorMQ(
endog_m, endog_quarterly=endog_q,
factors=factors, factor_orders=factor_orders,
factor_multiplicities=factor_multiplicities)
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is most likely coming up because you have an older version of Statsmodels installed. `DynamicFactorMQ` was introduced in version 0.12, so you should make sure that you're using a new enough version. You can check using:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
print(sm.__version__)
```

Answer (score 0):

statsmodels.tsa.statespace.dynamic_factor_mq.DynamicFactorMQ

Version 0.14.0

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).